# Define the random process $U(t) = A$ where $A$ is uniform over $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Define the random process $U(t) = A$ where $A$ is uniform over $[-1,1]$.

How would one sketch a sample  realization of this?? Can someone give me a simple idea so I could attempt my own definition?

I would then like to determine its temporal autocorrelation function and statistical correlation function.

My attempt at writing the Temporal Autocorrelation function in LaTeX...

$$R(\tau) = \lim \limits _{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int \limits _{-T/2}^{T/2} u(t+\tau)t(t)\, \Bbb dt.$$

Any other ideas on characteristics to determine are welcome! I was thinking of determining if the process is WSS/SSS? Ergodic?

Comment: If anyone can offer some LaTeX pointers (link to a website maybe), that would be appreciated :) seems my attempt didn't go as well as I hoped...

Comment: You haven't said enough about the process to determine any of these things. All you've told us is the one dimensional distributions.

Comment: @Ian that is where I was hoping to get some help. I'd like to use a simple process so my understanding can start from the ground up.

Comment: maybe something like X(t) = A cos(wt + Θ)?

Comment: So $X(t)=A \cos(wt + \theta)$ can be thought of as a process with a pre-chosen random amplitude. You can probably calculate your quantities of interest from there. I would encourage you to look into processes which make multiple random choices along the way. Brownian motion is a very common example, but there are others, like a sum of (possibly dependent) random variables. These have a lot of effects which are of central interest in theory/applications of stochastic processes.